# get index of loop in associative array using for ( key in array )

Tags: javascript

I have this associative array and use this code to loop but i need to get the index of loop for keys. I mean to get 0, 1, 2 ...

```
    var obj={'key1': 'value1','key2':'value2'};

for (var index in obj) {
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
        continue;
    }
    console.log(index);
    console.log(obj[index]);
}
```

Comment: `I have this array`, Is it? It's an object

Comment: Sorry, it's associative array

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is `index` *is* the index

Comment: The question is answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get the properties of the object as an array, then use [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```js
const obj = {
  'key1': 'value1',
  'key2': 'value2'
};

Object.keys(obj).forEach((key, index) => {
  console.log(key, obj[key], index)
})
```